# Python: .format() not rounding correctly

Tags: python, format, decimal, rounding

I have these two lists:

```
salePrices = [9.95, 14.95, 19.95, 24.95, 29.95, 34.95, 39.95, 44.95, 49.95]
percents = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
```

And then, using this for loop, I iterate through each percent and calculate the discounted price.

```
for percent in percents:

    for salePrice in salePrices: 
        newPrice = salePrice - ((percent / 100) * salePrice) 
        print("\t" + "{0:.2f}".format(newPrice), end = " ") 
    print()
```

This all works fine, except for one issue: some of the values calculated are not rounded properly.

For instance, 14.95 - (0.1 * 14.95) = 13.455, which should be rounded to 13.46 by .format(). However, the value printed is 13.45.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is it a problem with the method, format, itself?

Comment: Tried rounding before .format?

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
14.95 - (0.1 * 14.95) = 13.455
```

No, in IEEE doubles, `14.95 - (0.1 * 14.95)` is `13.454999999999998`. Which rounds down to `13.45` correctly.

[Here's the obligatory link to What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you want `14.95` to actually be exactly 14.95, rather than the closest binary fraction to 14.95, you may want to use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead of `float`. Of course `Decimal` is just as inexact, but the closest decimal fraction to 14.95 obviously really is 14.95. :)

Comment: SO questioners == computer scientists. lol

Comment: @Barmar: Hey, the paper was written back when anyone who wasn't a computer scientist didn't have access to a computer with an FPU. :)